# Altering the global/master UI from a background app in android

Tags: android, user-interface, listener, global

Is it possible for an android app to run in the background, listen to specific triggers and modify the visible application content in the screen (in both system and third party apps)?

For an example, A 2 finger tap should lead to a ripple effect on the screen. If the temperature is high, The screen turns more reddish. If I say "do a barrel roll", The entire UI does a "barrel-roll" like the google Easter egg. And this should happen whether the user is in the homescreen, settings or his Instagram.

The best working example I can give is the built-in "Magnification Gesture" provided by Android. Three taps anywhere will zoom everything up except for the keyboard and the navigation bar. And it doesn't zoom as an image, the touch points are preserved.

Is this possible to do without or with root? Do I need a framework like Xposed?

Thanks.

Comment: It is certainly not possible without root, for blindingly obvious privacy and security reasons.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that risk.